# cyclic subgroups of a $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-Dedekind $p$-group and  $\nu^*(G)$ denote
 the number of conjugacy classes of non-normal cyclic   subgroups of $G$. 
Does there exist  a normal second maximal 
subgroup $S$ of $G$ such that $\nu^*(S)< \nu^*(G)$?

(A subgroup $S$ is a second maximal subgroup of the group
 $G$ if $S$ is maximal in a maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$. 
 Since $G$ is a $p$-group, $S$ is a second maximal subgroup of $G$ if and only if $|G:S|=p^2$).

Any comment or answer will be appreciated!